vue js user state management is not working properly on vue js 3
working with Laravel 10 and Vue js 3 with vuex 4. I have following mainapp.vue file specially manage for menu items as well.
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="$store.state.user">
      <!--========== ADMIN SIDE MENU one ========-->
      <div class="_1side_menu">
        <div class="_1side_menu_logo">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;">Logo Image</h3>
          <!--<img src="/img/logo.jpg" style="width: 108px;margin-left: 68px;"/>-->
        </div>

        <!--~~~~~~~~ MENU CONTENT ~~~~~~~~-->
        <div class="_1side_menu_content">
          <div class="_1side_menu_img_name">
            <p class="_1side_menu_name">Admin</p>
          </div>

          <!--~~~ MENU LIST ~~~~~~-->
          <div class="_1side_menu_list">
            <ul class="_1side_menu_list_ul">
              <li><router-link to="/"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> Dashboard</router-link></li>
              <li><router-link to="tags"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> Tags</router-link></li>
              <li><router-link to="category"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> Category</router-link></li>
              <li><router-link to="adminusers"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> Admin users</router-link></li>
              <li><a href="/logout"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--========== ADMIN SIDE MENU ========-->

      <!--========= HEADER ==========-->
      <div class="header">
        <div class="_2menu _box_shadow">
          <div class="_2menu_logo">
            <ul class="open_button">
              <li>
                <Icon type="ios-list" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--========= HEADER ==========-->
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    data(){
       return {
          isLoggedIn : false, 
       }
    }, 
    created(){
       this.$store.commit('updateUser', this.user)
    }
}
</script>

my store.js file is
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

const store = createStore({
    state : {
        conuter : 1000, 
        deleteModalObj : {
            showDeleteModal: false, 
            deleteUrl : '', 
            data : null, 
            deletingIndex: -1, 
            isDeleted : false,

        }, 
        user: null, 
        
    }, 
    getters: {
        getCounter(state){
           return state.conuter
        }, 
        getDeleteModalObj(state){
            return state.deleteModalObj;
        },
       
      
        
    },

    mutations: {
        changeTheCounter(state, data){
            state.conuter += data
        }, 

        setDeleteModal(state, data){
            const deleteModalObj = {
                showDeleteModal: false, 
                deleteUrl : '', 
                data : null, 
                deletingIndex: -1, 
                isDeleted : data,
            }
            state.deleteModalObj = deleteModalObj
        },
        setDeletingModalObj(state, data){

            console.log('setDeletingModalObj mutation called');
        console.log('Data received:', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))); // Convert Proxy to plain object for logging


            state.deleteModalObj = data

            console.log('Updated deleteModalObj state:', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.deleteModalObj)));
        },
        updateUser(state, data){
            console.log('Updating user in Vuex:', data);
            state.user = data
        },
     }, 
     actions :{
        changeCounterAction({commit}, data){
            commit('changeTheCounter', data)
        }
    }

});

export default store;

I have following welcome.blade.php file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fullstack Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css">

    <script>
        (function () {
            window.Laravel = {
                csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                user: @json(Auth::user())
            };
            console.log('Laravel User:', window.Laravel.user);
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="app">
    <pre>{{ json_encode(Auth::user()) }}</pre>
    @if(Auth::check())
        <mainapp :user='@json(Auth::user())'></mainapp>
    @else
        <mainapp :user="false"></mainapp>
    @endif
</div>


    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>


but in my mainapp.vue file <div v-if="$store.state.user"> is not working it means not displaying my menu items and my console printing here but in welcome.blade.php file console.log('Laravel User:', window.Laravel.user); is printing current user object but mainapp.vue file console console.log('mainapp user',this.user); and store.js console.log('Updating user in Vuex:', data); is printing undefined how could I pass blade file user data to vue file via vuex

Your user is undefined in your Vue.JS app instance because he never takes the data from your Laravel app.
You pass them in the window but never affect them.
The best way to achieve this would be to pass your user in your Vue.JS app through the store at initialization.
Here is a simple example of the app div wrapper
<div id="app" :data-user="json_encode(Auth::user())"></div>

And the initialization of your Vue.JS app should look like :
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import MainApp from './MainApp.vue'
import store from './store.js';

const currentUser = document.querySelector('#app').dataset.user;
store.commit('updateUser', currentUser);

const app = createApp(MainApp)
app.use(store)

You can now access the user from the store.

It's data-user, not :data-user. And it already provided to client side through Laravel.user
